# How to Use vectorize or Apply instead of iterrows on pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, apply

I have 2000+ dataframes with two columns. I want to ngrams for on the columns and then create a new dataframe with ngrams. Here is my code. Its working fine. Just taking a lot of time.

I am currently using itterows to iterate through each row of each dataframe in each file. Is there an easier way to do this using vectorization or apply ?

```
import logging
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import math
import pickle
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import psutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

def create_combinations(file):
    initial_path ='./to_process/'
    final_path = './processed/'
    custom = pd.read_pickle(initial_path+file, compression='gzip')
    custom = custom.drop_duplicates(subset=['category', 'element'])
    custom['element'] = custom['element'].str.replace(r'([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))', r'\1 ')
    total_rows = len(custom.index)
    logging.warning('Processing element : ' + file + 'Number of rows to combine: '+ str(total_rows))
    # if total_rows > cores:
    #     partitions = math.floor(total_rows/cores)
    # logging.warning('Number of partitions : ' + str(partitions))
    if total_rows > 0:
        combined_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['category', 'element'])
        logging.warning('creating combinations')
        for key, data in custom.iterrows():
            words = data['element']#.split()
            logging.warning(words)
            words2 = words.replace('%', '%%').replace(' ', '%s')
            logging.warning('Number of words to combine: '+ str(len(words.split())))
            k = 0
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['category', 'element'])
            for i in itertools.product((' ', ''), repeat=words.count(' ')):
                df1.loc[k, 'element'] = (words2 % i)
                df1.loc[k, 'category'] = data['category']
                k += 1
            combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df,df1], axis=0)
            del df1
        combined_df.to_pickle(final_path + file, compression='gzip')
        combined_df.to_csv(final_path + os.path.splitext(file)[0]+'.csv') 
        del combined_df
        del custom
            # partitions = 1
        logging.warning('completed ' + file)
    else:
        logging.warning('No rows to process')





if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    partitions = 1 #number of partitions to split dataframe
    cores = 2 #number of cores on your machine
    path ='./to_process/'
    combi_path = './processed/'
    files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    pickle_files=[]
    for any_file in files:
        if any_file.endswith('.pickle'):
            if os.path.isfile(combi_path+any_file):
                logging.warning(any_file +' already processed.')
            else:
                pickle_files.insert(len(pickle_files),any_file)
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = len(pickle_files))
    start = time.time()
    async_result = p.map_async(create_combinations, pickle_files)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("Complete")
    end = time.time()
    print('total time (s)= ' + str(end-start))
```

enter code here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
# pylint: disable=I0011
# pylint: disable=C0111
# pylint: disable=C0301
# pylint: disable=C0103
# pylint: disable=W0612
# pylint: disable=W0611
import logging
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import math
import pickle
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import time
import gc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def create_combinations(file):
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    initial_path ='./training/pickles/standard and documentation/custom_elements/trial/'
    final_path = './training/pickles/standard and documentation/custom_element_combination_trial/'
    completed_file_path ='./training/pickles/standard and documentation/custom_elements_processed_trial/'
    custom = pd.read_pickle(initial_path+file, compression='gzip')
    custom = custom.drop_duplicates(subset=['category', 'element'])
    custom['element'] = custom['element'].str.replace(r'([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))', r'\1 ')
    total_rows = len(custom.index)
    logging.warning('Processing element : ' + file + 'Number of rows to combine: '+ str(total_rows))
    cat = []
    ele = []
    combined_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['category', 'element'])
    logging.warning('creating combinations')
    k=1
    for key, data in custom.iterrows():
        words = data['element']#.split()
        logging.warning(words)
        words2 = words.replace('%', '%%').replace(' ', '%s')
        logging.warning('Number of words to combine: '+ str(len(words.split())))
        for i in itertools.product((' ', ''), repeat=words.count(' ')):
            ele.append(words2 % i)
            cat.append(data['category'])
        lst = zip(cat,ele)
        if len(lst) > 200000:
            del cat
            del ele
            combined_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst,columns=['category','element'])
            del lst
            combined_df.to_pickle(final_path + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + str(k)+'.pickle', compression='gzip')
            combined_df.to_csv(final_path + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + str(k)+'.csv') 
            #del combined_df
            gc.collect()
            k+=1
    del cat
    del ele
    combined_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst,columns=['category','element'])
    del lst
    combined_df.to_pickle(final_path + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + str(k)+'.pickle', compression='gzip')
    combined_df.to_csv(final_path + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + str(k)+'.csv') 
    del combined_df
    gc.collect()
    del custom
    del words
    del words2
    logging.warning('completed ' + file)
    os.rename(initial_path+file, completed_file_path+file)
    os.rename(initial_path+os.path.splitext(file)[0]+'.csv', completed_file_path+os.path.splitext(file)[0]+'.csv')
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    partitions = 1 #number of partitions to split dataframe
    cores = 6 #number of cores on your machine
    path ='./training/pickles/standard and documentation/custom_elements/trial/'
    combi_path = './training/pickles/standard and documentation/custom_element_combination_trial/'
    processed_file_path ='./training/pickles/standard and documentation/custom_elements_processed_trial/'
    files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    pickle_files=[]
    for any_file in files:
        if any_file.endswith('.pickle'):
            if os.path.isfile(combi_path+any_file):
                os.rename(path+any_file, processed_file_path+any_file)
                os.rename(path+os.path.splitext(any_file)[0]+'.csv', processed_file_path+os.path.splitext(any_file)[0]+'.csv')
                logging.warning(any_file +' already processed.')
            else:
                df = pd.read_pickle(path+any_file, compression='gzip')
                rows = len(df.index)
                if rows > 0:
                    #if rows < 500:
                    pickle_files.insert(len(pickle_files),any_file)
                    # else:
                    #     continue
                else:
                    os.rename(path+any_file, processed_file_path+any_file)
                    os.rename(path+os.path.splitext(any_file)[0]+'.csv', processed_file_path+os.path.splitext(any_file)[0]+'.csv')
                del df
                gc.collect()
                del rows
                gc.collect()
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
    p = ctx.Pool(processes=cores, maxtasksperchild=1000)
    start = time.time()
    async_result = p.map_async(create_combinations, pickle_files)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("Complete")
    end = time.time()
    print('total time (s)= ' + str(end-start))
```